# Forzar que la fecha seleccionada en un input type date no pueda ser menor a la fecha actual

Tags: html5, bootstrap

Me preguntaba que podría hacer para validar que la fecha seleccionada en un `<input type="date>"` no pueda ser menor a la fecha actual.
Actualmente estoy utilizando este input:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha" id="fecha"  placeholder="Introduce una fecha" required/>
```

Espero que alguien pueda echarme un cable, saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes establecer la propiedad min de forma que, en los navegadores que muestran calendarios para seleccionar la fecha, no te permitirá seleccionar una fecha anterior a esta.

Sin embargo siempre podrá introducirla manualmente. Si quieres asegurarte de que no se introduzca un valor anterior deberías utilizar algún plugin de fechas o crear tu función de validación en javascript.

```html
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha" id="fecha"  placeholder="Introduce una fecha" required min="2016-05-24"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

No lo dices explícitamente, aunque creo que buscas una solución para [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) como indicas en la etiqueta.

Existen varios *widgets* de bootstrap que podrías emplear. Uno, por ejemplo, podía ser éste: [bootstrap-picker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) con un código como éste que hace lo que pides:

```css
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<input id="datepicker" type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha" id="fecha"  placeholder="Introduce una fecha" required/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                language: 'es'
            });
            $('#datepicker').datepicker('setStartDate', new Date());
        });
    </script>
</div>
```